# Python 3.8: Error running different Python environments from base directory's Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've recently had to do a reformat of my work computer, and am reinstalling Anaconda. I generally keep Anaconda's root `(base)` folder untouched, and create separate environments when I need to work with specialist Python modules instead of cluttering the `(base)` environment.

In the past, I was able to successfully run these different environments from the Jupyter Notebook installed in the `(base)` environment. I would go about doing so by installing `ipykernel` in the new environment (e.g. `my-env`), and then running the following commands:

```
(base)    activate my-env
(my-env)  conda install ipykernel
(my-env)  python -m ipykernel install --name "my-env" --display-name "My Python"
```

This would be done successfully, and give me the following message:

```
Installed kernelspec my-env in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\my-env
```

However, when I tried testing out the link in Jupyter Notebook using a standard `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` command, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a0d2faabd9e9> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    105 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    106 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 107 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    108 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    109 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
     26 import weakref
     27 
---> 28 import numpy as np
     29 
     30 import matplotlib

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    141     from .core import *
    142     from . import compat
--> 143     from . import lib
    144     # NOTE: to be revisited following future namespace cleanup.
    145     # See gh-14454 and gh-15672 for discussion.

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>
     23 # Private submodules
     24 from .type_check import *
---> 25 from .index_tricks import *
     26 from .function_base import *
     27 from .nanfunctions import *

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py in <module>
      9 from numpy.core.numerictypes import find_common_type, issubdtype
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.matrixlib as matrixlib
     12 from .function_base import diff
     13 from numpy.core.multiarray import ravel_multi_index, unravel_index

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 """
----> 4 from .defmatrix import *
      5 
      6 __all__ = defmatrix.__all__

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py in <module>
      9 # While not in __all__, matrix_power used to be defined here, so we import
     10 # it for backward compatibility.
---> 11 from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
     12 
     13 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
     71 """
     72 # To get sub-modules
---> 73 from .linalg import *
     74 
     75 from numpy._pytesttester import PytestTester

C:\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in <module>
     31 from numpy.core import overrides
     32 from numpy.lib.twodim_base import triu, eye
---> 33 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
     34 
     35 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Could someone advise me on what might be the issue? If it helps, my `(base)` environment has a `python` version of 3.8.3 and a `notebook` version of 6.0.3, whereas my new `my-env` environment has modules downloaded from conda-forge. It has a `python` version of 3.7.8 and an `ipykernel` version of 5.3.4.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 26 Oct 2020**
As requested, I have included the list of modules I have in both the `(base)` environment and the `(my-env)` environment. In general, the packages in `(base)` have been kept updated with respect to the `anaconda` module, whereas the packages in `(my-env)` are kept up-to-date with respect to `hyperspy`, which is stored in the `conda-forge` repository.

I have created PasteBin entries for them, as they exceed the character limit for this post.

[Link to list of modules in `(base)`](https://pastebin.com/WjPRGDwS)

[Link to list of modules in `(my-env)`](https://pastebin.com/BSZddJa4)

I also tried importing modules other than `matplotlib` and `numpy`, and was able to import `abc` and `time` without issue, for example. This seems to be an issue with the `(base)` version of Jupyter Notebook not being compatible with the `numpy` found in the `(my-env)` environment.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is indicating the error is arising from the **numpy** library. The fact that your Python and Ipkernel versions are different between your (base) and your (my-env) is further indication that there is incompatibility between your environments.

Can you provide the output from

**conda list**

from each environment?

When I tried to create a Python=3.8.3 environment the numpy version installed is numpy-1.19.2-py38hf89b668_1

I used the command

**conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.8.3 numpy**

When I tried to create a Python=3.7.8 environment the numpy version installed is numpy-1.19.2-py37h7008fea_1
I used the command

**conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.7.8 numpy**

In addition, why don't you consider installing ipkernel / jupyter notebook libraries that are consistent with respective versions of Python in each environment? This would always be the best solution to ensure dependencies are correctly aligned.

I also attempted to install ipykernel in both python=3.8.3 and python=3.7.8 along with **ipykernel** without  specifying version number.

Here are the versions of **ipykernel** that **conda**automatically chooses:

for python=3.8.3: ipykernel-5.3.4 |   py38h1cdfbd6_1

for python=3.7.8: ipykernel-5.3.4 |   py37hc6149b9_1

From what you have written your **ipykernel** versions are different. I do think this discrepancy is most likely coming from these differences of **ipykernel** versions

When you check your environments, verify that the channel source for **ipykernel** is the same.

**One Solution:** Consider downgrading the ipykernel in (base) to 5.3.4 version.

Comment: Hi @sreedta, thanks for the quick response. I've added the list of modules in both environments as PasteBin links at the end of the original question, as pasting them directly would exceed the character limit. The modules in the `(base)` environment are generally from wherever Anaconda downloads its stuff, and are kept updated with respect to the `anaconda` module. The ones in `(my-env)` are from conda-forge, and are kept updated with respect to `hyperspy`.

Comment: Further to that, I've tried importing other simpler modules like `time` and `abc` from the `(my-env)` module in the `(base)` environment's Jupyter Notebook, and those commands were able to run smoothly. Could it be an issue of compatibility between `(base)`'s Jupyter notebook and `(my-env)`'s `numpy` version? My understanding at the moment is that `ipykernel` is supposed to allow `(base)` Jupyter Notebook to interact with and run modules from different environments without depending on the modules in `(base)`. Is that not the case?

Comment: The lack of compatibility can arise from two sources and in your both factors are present. First is having libraries of different version and build and second is having libraries from different channels. It isnow known that sometimes conda-forge libraries may not align every time with libraries from other channels. I strongly recommend redoing your Base and My-Env using conda-forge and check if the problem persists. I encountered this very problem a week ago. The solution I suggested here worked for me based on the research I did here and elsewhere

Comment: The ipython and ipykernel in "my-env" are from different builds of Python and from different sources it appears. In the "base" environment these two libraries are from the same source and from have the same python signature. I also noticed numpy-base is missing in the "my-env". I strongly believe that if you set up a "base" and "my-env" completely from conda-forge for maximum consistency and test, your errors will likely go away.

Comment: Hi again @sreedta. Thank you for your explanation! Having read your comments, I decided to reinstall the packages in `(my-env)` with as many of them coming from the default conda channel as possible (`conda install -n my-env some-package -c defaults -c conda-forge`), and it seems to have cleared up the issue. I am able to run the `(my-env)` environment from Jupyter Notebook now! I'm curious though, does this mean that it is not possible to run older versions of Python (e.g. 2.7) from a Jupyter Notebook installed in a Python 3.8 environment?

Comment: @TheEponymousProgrammer good to hear that reinstalling worked! These days installation is half the battle. I'm myself looking into that question. I read on Anaconda Google Groups that Python 2.7 version is now end of life.The sooner a user transitions over to Python 3 the better was the advice from the anaconda support person. I began in 2.7 but now work completely in 3.6+; I think with 2.7 being EOL, there will be more and more libraries that will not have the back compatilibity requirement. So I do believe that inter-operability of 2.7 in 3.8+ will be untenable if not impossible

Comment: It's all thanks to your explanation, @sreedta! So, from what I've understood from this incident, Jupyter Notebook's ability to work with a different Python environment depends on the compatibility of said environment with the environment the Notebook is based in. In this case, the error is caused by the `numpy` module in `(my-env)` failing to be imported, as it was packaged differently from the `numpy` module found in `(base)`, due to being from a different conda channel. The issue was resolved by downloading as many of the modules in `(my-env)` as possible from the same channel as `(base)`.